# Creating new view in SSMS not working

Tags: azure, view, ssms

I apologize for this newbie question, but after years of working with MS Access I'm using my Azure subscription to setup my first Azure SQL Server.

The whole deployment process in Azure was very simple, and I'm now able to open my database in SQL Server Management Studio (latest version).

I've created a couple of test tables, set their PK and FK and defined a relationship between them.

Next thing I want to do is create a View. To keep things super simple, I follow these steps here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175503(v=sql.120).aspx

However, after clicking "New view" in step 2, I don't get the "Add table dialog box" that's supposed to pop up.

Instead, a blank query pops up with some instructions on how to create a new View template.

Am I missing something really obvious or does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

And I've also seen video instructions showing this "Add table dialog box" along with that fancy view designer and everything (very similar to Query designer in Access).

But no matter how much I try, I just can't make SSMS show that stuff to me.

I really appreciate your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing (SSMS v13.0.16000.28), this functionality is not yet available in SSMS when connected to an Azure SQL Database. You'll have to write the query in pure T-SQL. I don't think even the SSDT tools in Visual Studio support the view designer either.

There are regular updates to SSMS, so perhaps this feature will be added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your Azure database to a local database to a free SQL Express edition and create your views in the local SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), after that you can generate SQL script from your view and execute this script in your Azure Database